# Assigning a new boolean value to method?

Tags: java, boolean, assign

This is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();

    boolean shouldBeTrue = main.shouldBeTrue();
    shouldBeTrue = true;

    System.out.println(shouldBeTrue);       
    System.out.println(main.shouldBeTrue());

}//close main

public boolean shouldBeTrue(){
    return false;
}
```

It prints: true false

However I would to assing `main.shouldBeTrue() = true;`
which does not work.

My goal is to print `main.shouldBeTrue()` and have it print true instead of false.

Any ideas?
Thank you all so so much!

Comment: Are you trying to assign true to the method shouldBeTrue? Do you mean as a javabean with getter/setters?

Comment: I really don't understand this part: "My goal is to print main.shouldBeTrue() and have it print true instead of false." What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you can't assign values to methods, methods return values, what you can do is pass an argument to your method and return true/false depending on the argument

Comment: What does "assign to a method" even *mean*? What would, say, `List l = new ArrayList(); l.size() = 5;` do? Or `new FileInputStream("test.txt").read() = 'x';`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(main.shouldBeTrue());
```

The above is line is actually calling `shouldBeTrue()`, which is returning `false`.

Either pass a boolean variable to a method and return that values.

```
 public boolean shouldBeTrue(boolean myValue) {
        return myValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For main.shouldBeTrue() to return true, the  reference it returns should point to a value of true.

```
public class Main {
private boolean whatDoIReturn = false;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();

    Boolean shouldBeTrue = main.shouldBeTrue();
    main.shouldBeTrue( shouldBeTrue = true);

    System.out.println(shouldBeTrue);       
    System.out.println(main.shouldBeTrue());

}//close main

public Boolean shouldBeTrue(){
    return whatDoIReturn;
}

public void shouldBeTrue(boolean value){
    this.whatDoIReturn = value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, you can not assign a value to a method! What you need to do is maintain a variable that the method will return.

```
class MyClass
{
    private boolean myReturnValue = false; // can be set to either true or false

    public boolean shouldBeTrue()
    {
        return myReturnValue;
    }

    // Use this method to set the return value.
    public void setMyReturnValue( boolean newValue )
    {
        myReturnValue = newValue;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(myClass.shouldBeTrue()); // this will return false, which is currently the defined value of myReturnValue

        // Now we will change the return value.
        myClass.setMyReturnValue(true);

        System.out.println(myClass.shouldBeTrue()); // Now it will return true.
    }
}
```